# Can't run app with SQLite - Objective-c

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite

I'm trying to catch data from a sqlite3 database and list them in an UITableView. I have added the libsqlite3 framework but when I run it I get like 10 errors, one for each sqlite line. One of the messages I get is:

```
"_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
 -[AppDelegate initializeDatabase] in AppDelegate.o
```

Almost every message are like this but with different sql lines. initializeDatabase is a method where the database is opened.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you've got the libsqlite headers in your header search path, but the sqlite library itself is not linked to your target.

- Click on the target for your application.
- Open the Build Phases tab
- Choose 'Link Binary with Libraries', and add sqlite

[image]

Rather, then using the raw-C interface to sqlite, which is quite verbose you may wish to use an Objective-C wrapper. One popular wrapper is called [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), and this library can be quickly installed using the popular [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org) library manager tool.

CocoaPods will save you time, by automatically linking in your libraries, as well as any ***transitive dependencies*** (libraries that the library uses). While this is very convenient its still important to gradually learn what happens behind the scenes, so do try to set up some libraries manually, as you've done, as well.